# Trying to get multiple threads to get frames with capture.QueryFrame()

Tags: c#, multithreading, emgucv

So I've got a main class which gets the frames from my webcam and multiple threads that process the frames. I've locked the part of the main class that grabs the frame from the cam, so only one thread can process the same frame. Now I'm getting an External exception and I do not know why.
My main class:

```
public Image<Bgr, byte> GetImage()
{
    Image<Bgr, byte> returnable;
    Mat f = null;
    lock (locker)
    {
       do
       {
            f = capture.QueryFrame();
        } while (!capture.Grab());
        returnable = f.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
    }
    return returnable;
}
```

My thread:

```
Image<Bgr,byte> image;
image = o.GetImage(); //o is the main class
Image imag = image.ToBitmap();
string savePath = path + rofNumber + "/Original.jpg";
imag.Save(savePath); //Exception is on this line
toFind = o.GetNumbersFromDatabase();
labels = FindLabels(image);
```

The Exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException was unhandled
ErrorCode=-2147467259
HResult=-2147467259
Message=Er is een algemene fout opgetreden in GDI+.
Source=System.Drawing
StackTrace:
   bij System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder,    EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   bij OCR.Worker.Run() in C:\Users\...\Code\Visual Studio\OCR\OCR\Worker.cs:regel 178
   bij System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   bij System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   bij System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   bij System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem myself.
Since I'm working with multiple threads, I should have been more cautious with saving the images.

The problem was that one of the threads was saving the image and before it finished, another thread started saving to the same file, which caused the error.

The reason why I tried this in the first place is to get a kinda small slideshow of the camera feed.

**Conclusion:**

I used a different name per thread for saving the image!

In the end I've fixed this problem myself but I've learned that I need to be truely cautious with multiple threads...